# Portforwarding docker container to localhost

Tags: java, docker, solr

I'm trying to create a docker container so that I can connect to localhost:8180. But when ever I do following command and try to go to localhost I don't get any result

```
docker run -it -p 8180:8180 solrtest bash
```

My dockerfile is the following

```
FROM centos:7
COPY src/ /home/src/
RUN yum install -y \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/

RUN cd /home/src
RUN java -jar /home/src/app-solr-5-installer.jar -d "/home/app-solr"
RUN /home/app-solr/bin/app-solr start
EXPOSE 8180
```

The application itself is started so there is no issue and I expose the 8180 port. So I'm not very clear what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the application is running on port 8180. Do `docker exec -it container-id bash` and then check on which port your java application is running `netstat -anp | grep 8180` and so on. Also check docker  container logs using `docker logs container-id`

Comment: In the `docker run` command you show the application _isn't_ running, only a `bash` shell is.  Your Dockerfile should have a `CMD` line that starts the application.  (Any running processes get removed at the end of each `RUN` step, you cannot start a background process in a Dockerfile.)

Comment: [root@111124dfd9eb /]# netstat -anp | grep 8180
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8180          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

Comment: this is what I got when is do the netstat

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Dockefile in the following way:

```
FROM centos:7
COPY src/ /home/src/
RUN yum install -y \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/

RUN cd /home/src
RUN java -jar /home/src/app-solr-5-installer.jar -d "/home/app-solr"

EXPOSE 8180

CMD /home/app-solr/bin/app-solr start
```

After building, you can run it:

```
docker run -d -p 8180:8180 solrtest
```

You should not use `-it bash` option in this case because it means allocation tty and attach to bash. It will not run your application:

```
-t              : Allocate a pseudo-tty
-i              : Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: But when I do that the docker container is exited after a few seconds?

Comment: That simply means that command `/home/app-solr/bin/app-solr start` fails with some error. You can check it via `ps -a` to find out your `<container_id>`. After that, you can check logs via `docker logs <container_id>`. However, your comment does  not related to your question.

Comment: Also, please see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd for the reference.